# Store different fields from different tables to a temporary table

Tags: php, mysql, select, union, alias

I am trying to create a temporary table where it has two fields (user,pass) which was a combination from three tables

**TABLES**

```
agents
username | password

clients
username | password

admin
username | password
```

i want their data from their fields to be stored to a temporary table

**TEMPORARY TABLE**

```
temp_tbl
username | password
```

This is my MySQL query (i know this is a wrong syntax)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_tbl ENGINE=MEMORY 
AS (SELECT username,password FROM agents UNION SELECT username,password FROM clients UNION SELECT username,password FROM admin) AS col1, col2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty close

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_tbl ENGINE=MEMORY 
AS SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT username,password FROM agents 
 UNION SELECT username,password FROM clients 
 UNION SELECT username,password FROM admin) AS t1;
```

You have to wrap those three unions inside a another SELECT and you need to give that derived table an alias. Just one name please not two (t1 instead of col1, col2)

Unless you wrap the whole thing aaround another query as I have done, you will get a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

Your query should look like below rather. Per MySQL documentation you can use `CTAS` construct for creating `temporary` table as well.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_tbl
AS (SELECT username, password FROM agents 
UNION 
SELECT username, password FROM clients 
UNION 
SELECT username, password FROM admin);
```

Comment: @topic starter you may what to use `UNION ALL` to keep duplicates

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE VIEW all_user AS
   SELECT * FROM agents
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM clients
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM admin
```